# Как выполнить более 3 параллельных http запросов с помощью RxJava (+retrofit2) в Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava, retrofit2

Пытаюсь освоить работу с RxJava + retrofit2 + kotlin.

Как в этом участвует Observable в общем разобрался, даже научился объединять результаты 2-3 параллельных запросов по итогу выполнения всех с помощью Observable.zip, НО как похожим образом выполнить более 3 параллельных запросов не могу понять.

В исходном коде класса Observable есть метод

```
static <T1, T2, T3, T4, R> Observable<R> zip(),
```

но он не работает как

```
static <T1, T2, T3, R> Observable<R> zip()
```

в случае с тремя Observable на вход и `Function3<*,*,*,*>.`

Старался уже сделать первые три запроса с помощью zip, потом flatMap и тд, но всё не выходит. Чтение документации и примеров не помогают повернуть к нужному направлению. Смотрел в сторону Observable.combineLatest, но пришел к выводу (может ошибочному), что метод вернет результат первого выполнившегося Observable.

Если в целом, что я хочу:

У меня есть 4 метода, которые возвращают Observable:

- this.orderRepository.getStatuses():Observable
- this.orderRepository.getOrders():Observable
- this.userRepository.getUsers():Observable
- this.orderRepository.getTypes():Observable

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я должен скомпоновать эти методы, чтобы они выполнились параллельно, и в конце получить результат выполнения всех 4 методов в одном месте?**

Мои стыдливые попытки ниже. Это уже что-то испорченное, но я вообще не понимаю, что я должен сделать с 4 Observables, чтобы их всех в одном месте и вернуть в UI. + уже запутался с flatMap, map и так далее...

```
override fun buildUseCaseObservable(params: Params): Observable<OrderEntity> {

return Observable.zip(
                this.userRepository.getUsers(100, 1, ApiUserFilter(isManager = true)),
                this.orderRepository.getOrderStatuses(),
                this.orderRepository.getOrderTypes(),
                Function3<UserEntity, OrderStatusEntity, OrderTypesEntity, OrderEntity> { t1, t2, t3 ->
                    Zip(t1,t2,t3)
                }).map {
                    this.orderRepository.getOrders(params.limit, params.page, params.filter).flatMap {
                        it
                    }
                }

 }
```

---

Comment: Оказывается это была внутренняя ошибка обработки данных, поэтому Function9 не работала в zip. Пропустил ошибку, но всё же, есть какие то красивые способы кроме этого сделать множественные параллельные запросы и ограничены ли они чем то? Количеством ядер например, на всех ли устройствах одинаково выполнятся 8 параллельных запросов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip для четырех observable можно написать так:

```
Observable.zip<Status, Order, User, Types, Result>(
    getStatuses(),
    getOrders(),
    getUsers(),
    getTypes(),
    Function4 { status, order, user, type ->
        ...
    }
)
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. А есть какие либо аппаратные ограничения на использование этого метода? Например, если я попробую запустить 8 параллельных запросов на слабом android?

Comment: Zip ничего не знает про потоки (треды). Его можно запустить как на одном потоке, так и на нескольких. Почитайте про schedulers в rx (ну и, конечно, про операторы subscribeOn, observeOn). Кроме того, несколько потоков могут быть запущены как на одном физическом процессоре, так и на разных (распределением занимается операционная система).